# DataTables filter child rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable with child rows(see example here: http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html)

The search-input calls fnFilter() to filter the table, however it only filters the main rows. I would like the filter to search through the child rows aswell. I've searched a lot but havn't found any solution.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: post filter function code

Comment: The search/filter code is split up in a lot of different functions in the library.

Comment: so you what you want?) You want we write another filtering script for you or what?

Comment: There might already be some kind of modification made to the library to support this, that is what i'm looking for. There must have been lots of people running into the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out my question on this, @davidkonrad gave a nice workaround solution: [DataTables search child row content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471089/datatables-search-child-row-content/)