# datatables - preload data to array via ajax performs multiple connections

Tags: jquery, datatables

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471089/datatables-search-child-row-content/) tutorial I ended up with this code (that basically loads the child row content from an external file, parsed with JsRender, to an array) :

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    // carica il template del dettaglio
    $.ajax ({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "incaricodetail.html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            templateHtml = data; 
        }
    });
    var template = $.templates(templateHtml);
    var htmlOutput = template.render(d);

    return htmlOutput;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' ); 
    var dettagli = []; 
    var table = $('#tabellaDati').DataTable( {
        "data": <?= json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));?>,  
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent":
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs" href="incarico_edit.php?id=<?=$id;?>&pageFrom=<?=pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME ); ?>" title="Modifica"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>'+
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs delete-object" href="delete.php?id=<?=$row["id"]?>" delete-id="{$id}"" title="Elimina"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>'+
                    '<a class="btn btn-xs" href="#" id="mostraDettaglio" title="dettaglio"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>',
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        dettagli[meta.row] = format(data);
                    }

           },
           { "data": "id" },
           { "data": "protocollo" },
           { 
              "data": "dataIncarico",
              "type": "date",
              "dateFormat": "dd-mm-yyyy"
           }

        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#tabellaDati tbody #mostraDettaglio').on('click', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(dettagli[row.index()]).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

I don't know why, but the ajax call to the file incaricodetail.html is done three times (example, for two records I got 6 POST connections).

DataTables Debugger code: onucak

Whay could it be?
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon initialization, `render` is called on several occasions :

- display
- sort
- filter
- type (detection)

That is for *each row*! You can check the type of the render call through the `type` argument. A qualified guess is that your render function is called on `type`, `display` and `filter` - you have 2 rows, it gives 6 calls to the `format()` function, and by that 6 POST connections since you have turned `cache` off.

You can avoid that by simply :

```js
render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
   if (typeof dettagli[meta.row] == 'undefined') {
      dettagli[meta.row] = format(data);
   }
}
```

**Why is render called multiple times with different `type`?**
So you can return different data for different purposes. Lets say you have some HTML containing a checkbox as display, for sort you can pass 0, for filtering you can pass yes / no, for type you can pass number.

---

**Update**. initialise `dettagli[]` in `initComplete()` instead of `render()` :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete : function() {
        var api = this.api(),
            rowCount = api.data().length;
        for (var i=0;i<rowCount;i++) {
            dettagli[i] = format(api.row(i).data()[0]);
        }    
    }        
});
```

This should do the same as `dettagli[meta.row] = format(data);`, i.e call `format()` with the content of column #0 for each row.

You should also consider loading `incaricodetail.html` only once. Why load it over and over each time? It does not seem that the content of incaricodetail.html is meant to change, so would

```
var template;
$.get("incaricodetail.html", function(html) {
   template = $.templates(html);
});

function format ( d ) {
   return template.render(d);
}
```

not do exactly the same?

Comment: It works, thank you. Now I have anorher issue (data fetched again from disk when using pagination) but I will post it separately.

Comment: @alzambo, why dont you do the stuff in initComplete instead? Have all the way thought it was a little bit odd solution for you to use render, you can delete the new question and I will be happy to update this answer. simply just `initComplete  : function (for var i=0; .... { dettagli[meta.row] = format(data); }}`

Comment: I tried: "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
        for (i=0; i < settings.aoData.length; i++) {
            dettagli[meta.row] = format(data);
            }
        } but I cannot access `dettagli` or `meta`

Comment: ok i think I got something: with this loop `for (i=0; i < this.api().data().length; i++) {data = this.api().row(i).data();dettagli[i] = format(data);}` i have the correct connections, but when opening child row on, say, 2nd page it will reload from file

Comment: never mind.. I got also this one! Solved using delegated event as explained [here] http://api.jquery.com/on/ on **Direct and delegated events**. Thank you!

Comment: @alzambo, see update. Had some other urgent  things to do this evening.