# How to search 'Child' data with multiple records in Datatable?

Tags: php, datatable

This time, I am developing a Datatable with nested data, where inside the *Child* section, it has *tables* with list of the records. 
**The problem now is, I cannot search data inside *tables* in the Child section.**

[image]
*Figure 1: Search records by keyword '2960' and it filtered parents records only*

[image]
*Figure 2: View Child data*

[image]
*Figure 3: How to search these data (yellow underscore)?*

Question: Why the *Parent* [A] structure looks weird after clicked *Child's* plus icon?

I have already tried the solution provided by [@davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad)  in StackOverflow but failed. In that solution, it has a record only in each parent.

Referred: [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30476168/1481952)

Here is my code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dean8710/f6vq5gy2/6/)

```
enter code here
```

I expect the search function working for data in the tables inside the *Child* section too.
Please guide me, thank you.

Comment: _All_ relevant code _must_ be included _in the question itself_ and not as off-site links. Also, if you've tried some solution here in SO, link to that _solution_ instead of to the user that wrote it.

Comment: i already linked that tried solution. Code is long so, I put in jsfiddle, tq

Comment: Before posting a question, you need to do some proper debugging to narrow the issue down. If you ask about code, it **_must_** be posted into the question itself. That's not an opinion, it's how this site works. Otherwise, when those off-site links expires/gets deleted, this question will be useless for future visitors. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)