# DataTables - Searchable Dynamic Columns Per Row?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I'm working with a datatable that has child rows that must be searchable. I'm adding all columns to the parent row (as invisible) and drawing the children on click (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471089/datatables-search-child-row-content)). Though the data structure is a bit complicated, I got this to work well. I don't want to re-draw the table for every iteration, I want to simply update it, but the number of columns might be different (depending on the length of "steps"). If the number of steps increases for subsequent rows, this works fine, but if it decreases, I get a warning alert referencing a column for the previous parent row, even though the columns for the particular step don't include the previous column. Clearing the columns breaks the previous rows, and re-initializing the table loses the previous rows. Other than suppressing the alerts, any way to do this "correctly" ?

```
function updateHistoryTable(allStepData)
{
    var jobID = allStepData[allStepData.length - 1][0]['job_id'];
    var jobTime = new Date(allStepData[0][0]['job_time']).toLocaleString([], { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: true });
    var maxNumResults = Math.max(...allStepData.map(step => step[0]['step_result'].length));
    var columns = [
        { title: 'Time', data: 'jobTime' },
        { title: 'Job ID', data: 'jobID' },
        ];
        allStepData.forEach(function (steps, stepIndex) {
            steps.forEach(function (step) {
                if (Array.isArray(step['step_result'])) {
                    step['step_result'].forEach(function (result, resultIndex) {
                        var resultKeyPrefix = 'step_' + stepIndex + '_result_' + resultIndex;
                        columns.push({ title: 'Step ' + stepIndex, data: 'step' + (stepIndex), visible: false });
                        columns.push({ title: 'Object ' + resultIndex, data: resultKeyPrefix + '_object', visible: false });
                        columns.push({ title: 'Task ' + resultIndex, data: resultKeyPrefix + '_task', visible: false });
                        columns.push({ title: 'Response ' + resultIndex, data: resultKeyPrefix + '_response', visible: false });
                        columns.push({ title: 'Time ' + resultIndex, data: resultKeyPrefix + '_time', visible: false });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        // Initialize the DataTable
        if (!$.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#orch-history-table')) {
            histable = $('#orch-history-table').DataTable({
                columns: columns,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "lengthChange": false,
                "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip',
            });
            //Ignore alerts for now 
             $.fn.dataTableExt.errMode = 'ignore';
        }
        else
        {
            histable.columns(columns).draw();
        }
        histable.on('draw', function () 
        {
            $('#orch-history-table tbody tr').each(function ()
            {
                var $row = $(this);
            });
        });
        histable.off('click', 'tbody tr');
        histable.on('click', 'tbody tr', function (e) 
        {
            if ($(e.target).closest('tr').hasClass('child') || $(e.target).closest('.child').length > 0) 
            {
                return;
            }
            let tr = $(e.target).closest('tr');
            let row = histable.row(tr);
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
                row.child.hide();
            } else {
                var rowData = row.data();
                var childData = formatOrchHisData(rowData);
                row.child(childData, 'no-padding').show();
            }
        });
        var parentRowData = {
                jobTime: jobTime,
                jobID: jobID,
            };
        allStepData.forEach(function (steps, stepIndex) 
        {
            steps.forEach(function (step) 
            {
                if (Array.isArray(step['step_result'])) 
                {
                    step['step_result'].forEach(function (result, resultIndex) 
                    {
                        parentRowData['step' + stepIndex] = step['step'];
                        parentRowData['step_' + stepIndex + '_result_' + resultIndex + '_object'] = result['object'];
                        parentRowData['step_' + stepIndex + '_result_' + resultIndex + '_task'] = result['task'] || '';
                        parentRowData['step_' + stepIndex + '_result_' + resultIndex + '_response'] = result['response'];
                        parentRowData['step_' + stepIndex + '_result_' + resultIndex + '_time'] = new Date(result['time']).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit', hour12: true });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(parentRowData)
        try
        {
            var parentRow = histable.row.add(parentRowData).draw().node()   
            $(parentRow).css('cursor', 'pointer').css('color', 'rgb(94 183 255)');

        }
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.error(error); // Log the error to console
        } 
    }
     
        function formatOrchHisData(data) {
    
    var html = '<thead><tr><th class="child-row" style="width:50px" class="child-row text-center">Step</th><th  class="child-row" style="width:100px" class="child-row text-center">Object</th><th class="child-row" style="width:50px" class="child-row text-center">Task</th><th class="child-row" style="width:200px" class="child-row text-center">Response</th><th class="child-row" style="width:100px" class="child-row text-center">Time</th></tr></thead>';
    var stepIndex = 0;
    while (data['step' + stepIndex] !== undefined) {
        var stepKey = 'step_' + stepIndex;
            console.log(stepKey)
            console.log(data)
        var resultIndex = 0;
                while (
                data[stepKey + '_result_' + resultIndex + '_object'] !== undefined ||
                data[stepKey + '_result' + resultIndex + '_object'] !== undefined
                ) {
                var resultKeyPrefix = stepKey + '_result_' + resultIndex;

                html += '<tr class="child-row">' +
                    '<td class="child-row">' + data[ 'step' + stepIndex] + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="child-row">' + data[resultKeyPrefix + '_object'] + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="child-row">' + data[resultKeyPrefix + '_task'] + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="child-row">' + data[resultKeyPrefix + '_response'] + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="child-row">' + data[resultKeyPrefix + '_time'] + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                resultIndex++;
            }
        stepIndex++;
    }

    return '<table class="child-table">' + html + '</table>';
}
```